# MySQL multi-column UNIQUE KEY only unique when 1 column is not DEFAULT value

Tags: mysql, unique-key

Is it possible to create a multi-column `UNIQUE KEY` in `MySQL`, where it is only unique when 1 column is not the default value ie.

```
UNIQUE KEY (`col1`, `col2` IS NOT DEFAULT)
```

or

```
UNIQUE KEY (`col1`, `col2` = 1 )
```

...

I have a table structure like this -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `student_chapters` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `chapter_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `primary` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`student_id`,`chapter_id`);
```

The student can have multiple 'chapters', but only one can be the 'primary'. So if I have the following 3 rows for `student_id`=>`1`,

```
id | student_id | chapter_id | primary
1    1            1            0
2    1            2            0
3    1            3            1
```

I could insert this (primary is 0 [default])-

```
id | student_id | chapter_id | primary
4    1            4            0
```

but not this (primary is 1)

```
id | student_id | chapter_id | primary
4    1            4            1
```

since there is already the unique key (`student_id`=>1, `primary`=1) on row 3.

If a `UNIQUE KEY` like this is not possible, is there another way to do this?

Comment: I would just make another table `primary` with 2 columns, `student_id` (unique), and `chapter_id` (the primary chapter).

Comment: @Ignacio It feels a little redundant to do that, but I see how that could fix my issue.